# Problems with Netbeans' Javascript/Jquery Intellisense

Tags: javascript, jquery, netbeans, intellisense

I am having some problems with Netbeans' Javascript/Jquery Intellisense. I am using Netbeans 7.1 on Windows. For instance :

I have PHP project with :

- `jquery.js` in source files
- `index.php` in source files
- `script.js` in source files

Then I write something simple like this :

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("h1").click(function(){
               $('<h1>Hello</h1>').prependTo('body') ;
            });
        });

        var myDate = new Date();
        var m = myDate.getMinutes();
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>hello</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

With this example I get some Intellisense in `index.php` file but it is somehow not complete (as for me) for `$('h1').cl` Intellisense does not list `click` but shows somehting like this [image]

In the `script.js` I do not have any Intellisense for `jQuery` - only Javascript's.

I also don't get e.g. `Date`'s Intellisense. I only get this :

[image]

How can I fix this ?

Comment: On a sidenote, you can use $(function () { //code }); instead of $(document).ready(function () { //code });  and it does the same thing!

Comment: @AndrewWillis I know but I still do not get the Intellisense :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you have your IDE set up to hide features that are not supported in your target browsers?

for instance, in my Netbeans, it shows them with a strikethrough and says they aren't supported in Internet Explorer 5.5

Try changing your targeted browsers:

```
Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > JavaScript
```

Comment: I have tried changing these options but nothing helped. But still - for example: `getHours()` member function of `Date` is the most basic one isn't it ?

Comment: In that case I'd try updating the IDE plugins or uninstalling/reinstalling the IDE, you'll have to change your preferences again but you'll not lose your projects!